# material-ui/pickers v 3.x - how to customize the year renderer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In the `@material-ui/pickers` package (v3.x) (this is the recommended date/time pickers package in Material-UI v4.X) I'd like to customize the rendered output for the year selection for testing purposes. The package allows for customizing the rendered output for the days using `renderDay`, but I don't see a similar way to do that for the years displayed in the year selection view. I need to add a new attribute to the rendered `<div />` components that act as buttons for each year.

Am I missing something? Does anyone know how to accomplish this without forking the whole project?

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Here's a Code Sandbox to play with that includes customization for the rendered day components (via the `renderDay` prop). I'd like to be able to do something similar for the rendered year components.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-n8etg

[image]

Comment: Any online demo?

Comment: @keikai I've just added a link to a Code Sandbox to play with.